# Array.push() appears not to be working only when my application is running

Tags: node.js

I have a function that behaves correctly when i test it independently. However when running my full application, it's as if array.push() no longer works.

```js
module.exports.getLocalTypes = async (server_id, user_id) => {
  let localTypes = [];
  const getServer = await this.getRobotServer(server_id);
  const { settings } = getServer;
  console.log("GET ROBOT SERVER STATUS: ", settings);
  settings.roles.map(role => {
    console.log("TEST 1 ", role.role);
    role.members.forEach(member => {
      console.log("TEST 2", member);
      if (user_id === member) return localTypes.push(role.role);
    });
  });
  console.log("BEOFRE NO DUPES: ", localTypes);
  localTypes = Array.from(new Set(localTypes));
  console.log("SENDING LOCAL TYPES: ", localTypes);
  return localTypes;
};
```

When i run an independent test, i get the proper results:

```
TEST 1  default
TEST 2 @everyone
TEST 1  owner
TEST 2 user-810c7f96-47ad-4408-a8a2-3c9274fa2898
BEOFRE NO DUPES:  [ 'owner' ]
SENDING LOCAL TYPES:  [ 'owner' ]
Should return ['owner']:  [ 'owner' ]
```

When running my full app and using the exact same input to the function, i get this result instead:

```js
[1] TEST 1  default
[1] TEST 2 @everyone
[1] TEST 1  owner
[1] TEST 2 user-810c7f96-47ad-4408-a8a2-3c9274fa2898
[1] BEOFRE NO DUPES:  []
[1] SENDING LOCAL TYPES:  []
```

The function is extracting the values correctly from the database, and pulls up the correct owner and role, however it seems to fail at adding this value to the array. I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a promise, or using a try / catch. It makes no difference.

Output should be an array with types added, just like the first test result.

I'm still pretty new to JS, so maybe i'm missing something basic. 
For full context, the whole repo is online: 
https://github.com/jillytot/remote-control

Oh and one final note, running my test while the app is also running works. The test will still produce correct result, but the actual app still gets the wrong result.

Comment: Not sure it will solve your problem but you are misusing `map` and `forEach`. Your first `map` should be a `forEach`, and your `forEach` should probably be a `find`. Plus, pushing to an array does not return a new array, the operation is in-place and it returns the new length of the array.

Comment: Thanks @Remeus
I just solved it, it has nothing to do with anything here. 
At some point i must have accidently changed the one of the input alias's so the user was coming in as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it, it has nothing to do with anything here. 
At some point i must have accidently changed the one of the input alias's so the user was coming in as undefined. 
I missed it because it was something i confirmed worked earlier, so i overlooked it in my test.